# How do i get a text files content with swift and the dropbox API

Tags: swift, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

I'm trying to download a regular .txt file from my dropbox account which i have linked with a token, but i dont know how to get the content.
The only thing ive been able to find is this:

```
            // Download a file
            client.filesDownload(path: "/hello.txt").response { response, error in
                if let (metadata, data) = response {
                    println("Dowloaded file name: \(metadata.name)")
                    println("Downloaded file data: \(data)")
                } else {
                    println(error!)
                }
```

Which gives me nothing but a bunch of information about the file, but not its content.

Comment: I don't even have a filesDownload method o.O is it the same as `client.files.download(path:...)`? In that case, your `data` variable should have the contents of the file.

Comment: @Alex The data variable contains the size of the file for me

Comment: Ooh I see what the problem is. The type of data is `Data`, which only shows the size if you `print` it. You'll have to turn it into a string via:

`if let fileContents = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { print(fileContents) }`

Comment: Once you download the file to your device, you need to use the FileManager class to process it. See this answer to help get started: [How do you read data from a text file in Swift 3 (XCode 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822966/how-do-you-read-data-from-a-text-file-in-swift-3-xcode-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it prints the file size is that your `data` variable is of type `Data`. To print the actual contents, you'll have to convert it to a `String` first:

```
if let fileContents = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print("Downloaded file data: \(fileContents)")
}
```

---

#### Swift 1

Based on your using println, you might be using an older version of Swift. In that case, the code should look like this:

```
if let fileContents = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    println("Downloaded file data: \(fileContents)")
}
```

---

The good thing about the `Data` type is that you can convert it straight, for example, JSON:

```
guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
    return
}
//... do something with json ...
```

Comment: Glad I could help!